# How to program on Codesys to get readings from One wire(DS18B20) temperature sensor on Beaglebone Black?

Tags: sensors, beagleboneblack, plc, beagleboard, codesys

I am new to Codesys(LD programming).

The program I have made is not returning any readings from the sensor connected on my beagle-bone though it shows no errors.

**Unique ID**

I have watched tutorials for the same task but for Raspberry pi, there you can give the Unique ID of the sensor in device directly. Unfortunately for beagle-bone black there is no inbuilt One wire master function comes with the CODESYS control for beaglebone sl. So i am unsure where to write the unique ID of the sensor.

[Picture of the LD program I have made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMLjb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I've searched and tested, the Beaglebone doesn't seem to be OneWire compatible, because the OneWire connector doesn't appear in the tree like it does when you include a Raspberry Pi. You need this connector to attach the OneWire_Master and Sensors, and then configure for use in the program.

Here I created a project with **Beaglebone SL**, yours is the Black model, but we can see the same thing in your project photo:

[image: Project with BeagleBone SL]

Here I created a project with the **Raspberry Pi**:

[image]

Maybe 3S/Codesys will develop and include a connector in the future to the Beaglebone, try [this forum](https://forge.codesys.com/forge/talk/), someone there may have some additional information...

Comment: internet says that I could use Raspberry pi SL  library of DS18B20 for beaglebone SL But there is no examples for that.

Comment: Also I connected DS10B20 to Beaglebone and I am getting values, but with python program. (So Beaglebone is One wire compatible)

Comment: Not that Beaglebone itself isn't OneWire compatible, but Codesys for Beaglebone doesn't have the ready-made connectors, which rely on a Codesys development. There may be a way to make this access, unfortunately I don't know a way to help you with this, what I indicated is what the documentation available at the moment shows.